# Value object static Factory

Tags: typescript, express, domain-driven-design, bcrypt

I have some problematic for now that i want to know ur opinions.
First, i have a userPassword which represent a value object within my user domain model. i would like to validate 2 cases when creating my userPassword object :

- Not empty value of password
- Hash the given value
  Thus, i don't really know the best approach to achieve it.
  Now that the problem was exposed, take a look at my code below :

  ```
  export class UserPassword {
    private readonly value:string

   private  constructor(value: string) {

       this.value =  value
   }
    public getValue():string {
        return this.value
    }

    // My static factory in which i want to apply my validations cases

    static create(password: string):UserPassword {
        // Need to be implemented
    }
    private async hashPassword(password: string):Promise<string>{
       return await bcrypt.hash(password,10)
    }
    async comparePassword(password:string):Promise<boolean> {
        let hashed: string = this.value
        return await bcrypt.compare(password, hashed)
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: FYI, there's no reason to use the `await` in `return await fn()`.  You're returning a promise either way so you can just do `return fn()` directly without the `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For validations purposes, i just done some verifications before creating my password object. Because i think that it's always relevant to defined validation logic in the object contruction.
So here is my solution:

```
export class UserPassword {
    private readonly value:string

     constructor(value: string) {
        if (value === "") {
            throw new UserInputError("Password must be filled")
        }
        else {
            this.hashPassword(value).then(r => console.log(r))
            this.value =  value
        }
   }
    public getValue():string {
        return this.value
    }

    private async hashPassword(password: string):Promise<string>{
        return bcrypt.hash(password,10)
    }
    async comparePassword(password:string):Promise<boolean> {
        let hashed: string = this.value
        return  bcrypt.compare(password, hashed)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
I mean if you want to be super sure, never store, in memory neither, the clear value of the password

```
// My static factory in which i want to apply my validations cases

  static async create(password: string):UserPassword {
      if (!password || password.trim().length() == 0) {
           throw Exception("password not valid")
      }
      var hash = await bcrypt.hash(password,10)
      return new UserPassword(hash)
  }
```